# SSH from Mac (host) to Virtual Machine running Windows 10 (guest)

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine

I'd like to SSH into my virtual machine to "remotely" edit some files. I'm running Mac OS X (host), and the VM (on VMWare) is running Windows 10 (guest).

Is there a way of achieving this? What do I have to setup on the guest side for this to work?

Comment: SSH does not natively exist on windows computers, so installing software to enable it would require administrator rights.

Comment: Thx, I've installed OpenSSH on Windows (with admin rights) from [here.](http://www.mls-software.com/opensshd.html)

Comment: In virtualbox this is doable by selecting bridged networking. Never used VMWare but there is likely a similar option.

Answer (score 0):

You can remotely run commands on the VM by enabling telnet server in control panel -> programs -> Install windows features. All traffic in telnet is sent in plain text so its insecure. Setting up a private virtual switch between the host and guest would reduce the security risk.